# How do I get this jQuery slider to stop?

Tags: jquery, slider

I have a problem. I use this jQuery script (http://musca.se/full-window-width-jquery-tools-content-slider-demo/) to slide my portfolio stuff but I'm not a pro in jQuery at all and after a lot of searching I now ask you. How do i get the slider to stop sliding when I press prev or next?

Here's what the code looks like:

```
$(function() {
        // Sets the slides width on page load
        var i = $(window).width();
        if (i > 319){ $('#items > div').css({ width: i }); }
        // Scrollable and navigator plugin settings.
        $("#slider").scrollable({ circular: true, touch: true, easing: 'easeInQuart', speed: 900}).navigator({ navi: '#navigation' }).autoscroll({ autoplay: true, autopause:false, interval: 2000 });

        // Window resize code
        window.api = $("#slider").data("scrollable");
        $(window).resize(function() {
            var a = window.api.getIndex();
            var w = $(window).width();
            if (w > 319) {
                var l = a * w
                $('#items').css({ left: + - +l });
                $('#items > div').css({ width: w });
            } else {
                $('#items > div').css({ width: 300 });
            }
        });
    });
```

My navigation buttons look like this:

```
<div id="navigation-wrapper">
    <span class="prev lefty"><img src="img/left.png" /></span>
    <span class="next righty"><img src="img/right.png" /></span>
</div>
```

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your timeout as a variable before you call it:

```
var st;

$('.prev').on('click',function(){
    st = setTimeout("$('#slider')", 999999);
});
```

You can clear it like this:

```
clearTimeout(st);
```

EDIT:

Seeing as the previous code was based on an outdated example, you can try this:

```
$('#navigation-wrapper').on('click', 'span', function(){
    $('#slider').autoscroll({ autoplay: false, autopause:false, interval: 0 });
}
```

This should hopefully re-initialise the slider with an autoplay value of false, meaning it will stop rotating by itself. However, I'm not familiar with this plugin so this is a guess at best. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm not sure what you mean, since I'm a totally worthless javascript coder. How do you mean this could be implemented in my code?

Comment: You edited your code - where have the prev and next buttons gone?

Comment: That was just something i tried out but it didn't work. When i press the image with the class "prev" or "next" the slider changes slide. http://musca.se/full-window-width-jquery-tools-content-slider-demo/html4-css2-responsive.html that is the demo i've been following..

Comment: This is more of a question about the plugin than a generic jquery question. Have you tried setting autopause to false?

Comment: It probably is sadly. It is set to autopause:false right now but if I change it to true, the slider will pause when i hover it.

Comment: Do you want the slider to stop completely when you click previous or next, and never move again?

Comment: Exactly, so that when you press a navigation button (prev or next) the slider stops to autoplay but you should be able to change slide yourself.

Comment: Updated answer with new code. No guarantees, but it might do the trick.

Comment: It still doesn't work :( It's like the script doesn't care about what i put in there..

Comment: This is specific to the plugin, so you're better off going to the plugin's creator for support.